# How to unzip a lot of gzip txt files and read through each one?

Tags: python, loops, gzip, txt

What sort of loop would I use? I have tried some sort of for loop but I cannot get my code to review each file and keep going through all of the files. I have hundreds of files that I need analyzed. I saw somewhere that someone used this code:

```py
import glob
import gzip

ZIPFILES='name.gz'

filelist = glob.glob(ZIPFILES)
for gzfile in filelist:
    # print("#Starting " + gzfile)  #if you want to know which file is being processed  
    with gzip.open(gzfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
             print(line)
```

but how do I loop this to keep reading more files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to get a list of all the files in a directory, and then iterate over that list.

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.gz'):
    with gzip.open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```